# iPhone 5: view size changes after playing a video

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, iphone-5

I'm in the process of updating an older app I've developed to new iphone 5 screen dimensions. I have a page that I was able to stretch vertically but I have a weird issue.

## Problem

Currently the page looks like this:

[image]

Everything is stretching as normal.  As you can notice, at the top I have a button that links to a video.  When you press this button, the default iOS "videoView" we'll call it, comes up and plays my video like normal.  When I press the "done" button to exit the video, here is what my page looks like when I return.

[image]

You can see the view gets stretched horizontally and vertically.  Springs and struts for this view are as follows:

[image]

Any idea what might be going on here?

**EDIT**

Here is the view hierarchy. It's custom.

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to know more about the view hierarchy. Is that a real UITabViewController or a custom job? How are the views set up to display the content in your screenshot? Which view's size info are you displaying?

Comment: That video would be nice to have.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the exact same problem, but I think there is a WWDC 2012 video showing a problem with the evolution of ViewControllers, perhaps it is the same problem you are facing.

The video is : Session 236 - The Evolution of View Controller on iOS

and also the sampling code of this video can be usefull.

To get the video go to you apple developer account and videos are freely downloadable through iTunes.

[Link to WWDC 2012](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/)

Hope it will help you

**EDIT**

I went quickly through the video and I am not sure it is the same problem as you. However this video explains new iOS6 features in the layout and hierarchy of the view controllers which I hope will help you.